# about properties of the operator $T_f(g) := f\cdot g$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, compact-operators

let $f \in C([0,1])$ and $T_f:  L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ and $T_f(g) := f\cdot g$ prove :

1)$T_f$ is well define , linear and bounded and find $|| T_f ||$ .

2 )if  $T_f$ be compact operator then $f=0$

i can prove $T_f$ is  linear.

Comment: Are $f,g$ real valued?

Comment: @copper.hat .yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer of the second part: Let $a \in [0,1]$ Define $g_n(x)=\sqrt n$ for $|x-a|<\frac  1n$ and $0$ for all other $x$. Then $(g_n)$ is bounded in $L^{2}$. If $T$ is compact then $(fg_n)$ has  convergent subsequence. Note that $(fg_n) \to 0$ almost eveywhere. Hence the subsequence can only converge to $0$. If $|f(a)| >0$ then $\int |fg_n|^{2} \geq c \int |g_n|^{2}$ for some $c>0$ and $n$ sufficiently large. We got a contradiction since $\int |g_n|^{2}$ does not tend to $0$.  Thus $f$ vanishes at every point $a$.

Hints for first part: The norm of $T_f$ is $M$, the supremum of $|f|$. Clearly $\|Tf\| \leq M\|g\|$ so $\|T_f\| \leq M$. There exist $x$ such that $M=|f(x)|$. Now there exists $r>0$ such that $|f| >M-\epsilon$ on $(x-r,x+r)$. Take $g(y)=\frac  1 {\sqrt {2r}} $ for $|y-x| <r$ and $0$ for all other $y$. Then $\|g\|=1$. Can you show that $\|T_f\| \geq \|T_f(g)| \geq M-\epsilon$?.

Comment: why $T_f$ is bounded ?

Comment: @amirbahadory  I have edited my answer. The fact that $\|T_f\| \leq M$ is obvious from the definition of norm of an operator.

Comment: i can't show $\|T_f\| \geq \|T_f(g)| \geq M-\epsilon$.

Comment: @amirbahadory $\int |f(x)g(x)|^{2}dx \leq M^{2}\int |g(x)|^{2}$ whre $M=\sup_x |f(x)|$. Take square root and then supremum over all $g$.

Comment: $\int |f(x)g(x)|^{2}dx \geq  \frac 1 {2r} (M-\epsilon)^{2} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} 1 dx$ @amirbahadory

Comment: Why $g_n$ is bounded?

Comment: @amirbahadory $\int g_n^{2}=n(\frac 2 n)=2$ so $(\|g_n\|_1)$ is bounded in $L^{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

For 1) Show $T_f g \in L^2$ and use the Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

For 2) Show that $T_f$ is self adjoint. Then $T_f$ has a non zero eigenvalue. This says something about $f$. And the compactness allows you to deduce $f=0$.

Comment: why  $T_f$ is self adjoint ?

Comment: You need to show that. You can determine the adjoint in the usual way.

Comment: how we can find $|| T_f ||$ ?

Comment: The Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

With $f$ continuous you can get away with an "easy" argument: assume that $f$ is not identically zero, so that it's, say, positive on an open interval; call it $I$. On $I$ you can build an orthonormal sequence by normalizing appropriate bump functions with disjoint supports. Elements of this sequence all have unit norm, but any limit point of the images would have to be zero on $I$ (here we use the definition of $I$).